# graphite queries and confusion around time

Tags: timezone, graphite

I am doing a http query on my graphite server:

```
curl 'http://example.com/render?from=06:04_20140430&until=06:08_20140430&target=servers.server1.memory.MemFree&rawData=true'
servers.hub-eu.memory.MemFree,1398859500,1398859740,60|1854017536.0,1851564032.0,1843437568.0,1868869632.0
```

The output should start from 06:04 but timestamp 1398859500 corresponds to 12:05. Why would that happen?

Additional info: the graphite server's timezone is EDT. Timezone for server1 is GMT.

Answer (score 0):

What timezone is set in [local-settings.py](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-local-settings.html)? The default is [America/Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), which is UTC−06:00.

You can specify a time zone to convert all times into for a request by setting [tz](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html). E.G.

```
curl 'http://example.com/render?from=06:04_20140430&until=06:08_20140430&target=servers.server1.memory.MemFree&rawData=true&tz=UTC'
```

Comment: No matter what tz I am passing, the output is same. Any pointers?